# Do any Roman writings use the phrase Casus belli?

Tags: roman-empire

I have long had it assumed [Casus Belli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_belli) was a term used by the Romans (probably because it's Latin), but apparently not so?

Comment: Latin continued in legal and other academic domains long after the Romans and many well-known expressions are from after their time, so it wouldn't be too surprising to find no evidence of it from back then.

Comment: This question might be better suited for latin.SE.

Comment: Do you mean ["*casus belli*"](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:casus),  "*the casualties of war*" in the nominative case, either singular or plural; or ["*causam belli*"](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:causa), "*the cause of war*" in accusative singular.

Comment: @ed.hank: He links the Wikipedia entry for the former, not the latter. That's why OP needs to answer not assorted bystanders.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - by latter, i mean if you read the wiki page, it is talking about causes of war not casualties of war.  But I agree he needs to clarify himself.

Comment: In practice, the Romans viewed "Because we haven't conquered you" as a sufficient *casus belli*, so it would not mean in their time what it means now.

Answer (score 6):

Livy uses this term,  Livy, History of Rome, Volume XII: Books 40-42 (pg 444 LOEB classics version) edit: though from the comment that is better translated as 'casualties' of war rather than 'cause'.

"viro forti dignum sit, patiatur quodcumque ***casus belli*** tulerit, aut victor liberet"

Another example of Livy using roughly this term (but with the meaning I assume the author is looking for) is in Livy Book XXVIII part 7 from this [link](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/livy/liv.28.shtml)

"praeuertendum id ratus legatis cum benigno responso dimissis—se neque ***causam eius belli*** fuisse nec moram, si modo aequa et honesta condicione liceat, paci facturum"

And later in the same book part 14 (same link as above)

"Romanum Poenumque, quos inter ***belli causa*** esset, pari robore animorum armorumque concursuros"

Also see Livy Book XXI (College Series of Latin Authors, Greenough & Peck 1893, pg 40)

"Cathagine acta decreta que forent seque non ducem solum sed etiam ***causam esse belli***"

Seutonius uses a slightly different version that means the same thing, probably having to do with Latin conjugations but it has been 30 years since I last had a Latin class, but in  Lives of Caesars part 5 Claudius (pg 48 in the LOEB classics version) he writes:

"ut legatis consularibus simul cum exercitu et triumphalia darentur, ne ***causam belli*** quoquo modo quaererent. Aulo Plautio etiam ovationem decrevit ingressoque urbem"

Added correction from Pieter Geerkens: "casus belli" is "the casualties of war" in the nominative case, either singular or plural; and "causam belli" is "the cause of war" in the accusative singular

Comment: Correction please: ["*casus belli*" is "*the casualties of war*"](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:casus) in the nominative case, either singular or plural; and ["*causam belli*" is "*the cause of war*"](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:causa) in accusative singular.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - added your comments to the answer, thank you for your Latin corrections,  like I said it has been decades since I was last in Latin class and even then remembering all the different cases, conjugations, etc, was always a pain.

Comment: The question is about "casus" not "causa".

Answer (score 3):

Casus belli means "an act of war". It does not seem to be used in this sense by any classical Roman writer, but it is a well-established term in modern international law. "Casus" is not the same word as "causa" (cause). The confusion of "casus belli" (act of war) with "causa belli" (cause of war) is a common blunder.

Comment: Technically, in its most common meaning *casus belli* means more something like "an occasion for war", but your point is still valid.